# MODULE_NOT_FOUND error when running the dbmigrate command

Tags: node.js, modulenotfounderror, dbmigrate

I did the following:

```
npm install --save sequelize-cli
npm install -g db-migrate
npm install sequelize-cli@2.1.0 --save
```

When I run the `dbmigrate` command, I get the following error. What would be the reason?

```
>      PS C:\Users\usuario\Documents\GitHub\InteraccionAplicaciones_ModuloGimnasio_Back>
> dbmigrate           internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892 throw err;
> Error: Cannot find module
> 'C:\Users\usuario\Documents\GitHub\InteraccionAplicaciones_ModuloGimnasio_Back\.migration'
> Require stack:
> - C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\dbmigrate\lib\migrate-cli.js
> - C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\dbmigrate\bin\migrate
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15) at Function.Module._load
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27) at Module.require
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19) at require
> (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18) at Object.<anonymous>
> (C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\dbmigrate\lib\migrate-cli.js:8:16)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14) at
> Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32) at
> Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12) at
> Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19) { code:
> 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: [
> 'C:\\Users\\usuario\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\dbmigrate\\lib\\migrate-cli.js',
> 'C:\\Users\\usuario\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\dbmigrate\\bin\\migrate'
> ] }
```

Comment: Did you read the error message?  What does `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` with `migrate-cli.js` and`migrate` mean to you?  What have you tried so far to resolve your issue?

Comment: Hi Allan, I installed migrate, what do you think?

Comment: Is `migrate` and `migrate-cli.js` modules you can install?

Comment: yes and ... i dont know .... : 
 C:\Users\usuario\Documents\GitHub\InteraccionAplicaciones_ModuloGimnasio_Back> npm install -g migrate   
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\migrate
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists